# Can't run dotCMS - cms500Page

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, dotcms

I downloaded the zip file of dotCMS two days ago from http://dotcms.com/download/. I followed *exactly* step by step the instructions of dotCMS documentation and I managed to connect correctly the dotCMS with mySQL (http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/DatabaseConfiguration).

The problem is that when I am running the Apache tomcat (by executing the `startup.bat` file), a blank page appears on localhost:8080/ and sometimes a page appears containing the number 500(of course in the ROOT folder in webapps I have the dotCMS files). Also in `catalina.log` I see the following error:
`ERROR org.apache.jsp.portal._500_jsp - cms500Page`

Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your database is not connecting or is misconfigured.  Make sure that you point dotCMS to an existing, though empty, db.  Also insure that your username/passwords work using the exact same ip/hostname as your connection string.

You will find more information about your db error in the log files, either the tomcat/logs/catalina.out or the tomcat/webapps/ROOT/dotsecure/log/dotcms.log

See this page for more information on how to install dotCMS
http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few weeks back and managed to resolve it.
The issue might be because you didn't use terminal command to extract the package as mentioned [here](http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/installing-from-release).

Try using :

```
tar -zxvf dotcms_X.X.tar.gz
```